# Transfer data of csv file to redshift recursively

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have as scenario where in there are about 90 CSV files in s3 i want my glue job to pick one file at a time(not all at once)and load data to red shift. How can I achieve this?

I have no idea what to try and I want some one to help me

Comment: It sounds like you want "sequential" loading of the files.  There are lots of ways to do this but almost all require some external to Redshift process.  The best way to do this IMHO is a lambda function that reads S3 and then issues the SQL to Redshift Data API.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please refer me to an example or outline on how to achieve this?

Comment: Here's a code example of a python lambda for issuing SQL to Redshift - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274931/how-to-insert-data-in-redshift-using-either-of-boto3-or-psycopg2-python-librarie

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't write it for you. Please [edit] your question and add the code you've tried. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?
If you don't know how to start, tutorials and text books would be a better choice. See also [ask].

Comment: @Robert redshift data loading strategy is legion and complicated. The question is crystal clear if u know redshift and its loading capabilities. They are looking for a capability that’s doesn’t really exist in the docs so they couldn’t try any code in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your files are stored in folder A, the process involves creating a new folder B, named something like 'processed_files.' The purpose is that each time you initiate the glue job, the script will search for the oldest file in A that hasn't been processed (not yet present in B). It will then proceed to process the file, and upon successful completion, relocate or duplicate the file from A to B.

Use boto3 for this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use redshift spectrum (which just uses a glue catalog/table under the hood) and use the “$path” pseudo column which tells you the s3 filename. That way you can query the data sorted by filename without even ingesting it into redshift.